# Invertible elements in $Z/27Z$ form a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

From some lecture notes, it is also claimed that invertible elements in $Z/p^{3}Z$ is cyclic multiplicative group. How to show this?

Comment: Are you concerned more with the $p=3$ case? Because the title and your question don't match.

Comment: Yes, the p=3 case is enough. But it would be more helpful if there is proof for the general case.

Comment: $2$ is a primitive root mod $3$, $9$, $27$, ...

Comment: There's a flaw in the accepted answer of that duplicate I found, @DietrichBurde.

Comment: The invertible elements of $Z/2^3Z$ do **not** form a cyclic group. If $p>2$ is prime, then it is  true.